# Запрос не работает так, как мне видится он должен работать

Tags: mysql

[image: Есть таблица в MySQL]
Есть таблица в MySQL
Хочу получить все строки с уникальными значениями value и делаю такой запрос:

    `SELECT * FROM test WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM test GROUP BY value)`

И мне выводит все значения (все 7 строк).
Я с MySQL недавно работаю и хочу разобраться чего я здесь не понимаю.

По отдельности всё работает:

`SELECT id FROM test GROUP BY value` - возвращает 2, 3, 1, 6.
`SELECT * FROM test WHERE id IN (2, 3, 1, 6)` - возвращает все 4 строки с данными id (и соответственно уникальными значениями.

А вместе работать не хочет...
P.s. Если можно, то дайте разжеванный ответ т.к. скорее всего это тонкости работы `GROUP BY` и я что-то делаю не так. А кучу заумных и оптимальных конструкция я сейчас просто не пойму...

Comment: Вы хотите получить строки для которых value встречается только один раз или все различные value по одному разу?

Comment: В вашем запросе строка выбирается если value попадает в результат запроса. Конечно будут выведены все строки, так как их value будет содержаться в результате подзапроса.

Comment: Покажите хотя бы желаемый результат...

Comment: @becouse - Увы, не очень понял, что вы говорите... я хочу получить все строки (в данном случае 4 строки) на выходе, чтобы в них не было повторяющихся значений value

Comment: *По отдельности всё работает* Это - случайность, что возвращается именно такой набор для первого запроса. Включите ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY - и сервер скажет, почему запрос некорректен.

Comment: *я хочу получить все строки (в данном случае 4 строки) на выходе* Покажите, какие КОНКРЕТНО записи Вы желаете получить. Почему не, скажем, ID=(2,5,7,6)?

Comment: @Akina - Должно выдать записи с id = 1, 2, 3, 6 т.к. в каждой из них своё уникальное значение value. Можно и с ID=(2,5,7,6)

Comment: Почему для value=2 выведена именно запись id=3, а не id=5?

Comment: Можно и id=5 - задача получить уникальное значение. Почему так  - предположу, что берет первую попавшуюся запись. Вот, наверное, тут не могли бы разжевать:)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98447/discussion-between--and-akina).

Comment: А точно нужно ещё и поле `name`? А если нужно - точно нужно, чтобы `name` и `id` были взяты из одной и той же записи? И - укажите точную версию MySQL.

Comment: Я хочу получить уникальные значения в value и вывести полностью все строки, где такое имеется. Мне не принципиально какие. Где value=3 меня устроит строка и с id=1 и с id=4 и с id=7.
Это тестовый пример - если часть полей убрать, то оно должно лучше работать (имхо). Предположим, что нужны все поля, но и иное можно - если это поможет мне разобраться что не так:) Версия MySQL - 5.6.37

Answer (score 2):

```
-- требуется MySQL версии 8+
WITH cte AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY value ORDER BY id ASC) rn
             FROM source_table)
SELECT id, name, value
FROM cte
WHERE rn=1

-- работает и на 5+, предполагается, что id - уникальное
SELECT t1.*
FROM source_table t1
JOIN (SELECT MIN(id) id
      FROM source_table
      GROUP BY value) t2 ON t1.id=t2.id
```

Comment: Можете пожалуйста разжевать почему именно так, а не иначе. Функция MIN, я так понимаю используется чтобы убрать неопределенность для MySQL. Хорошо, а t1 и t2 - это что? У меня одна таблица была

Comment: @Дмитрий t1 и t2 - это псевдонимы (алиасы). Нужны, чтобы различить, из какой именно таблицы брать поле, если в обеих таблицах есть поле с таким именем.

Comment: Можете пояснить ещё - как мы вторую таблицу получили? Увы, не так хорошо я MySQL знаю...

Comment: В качестве второй таблицы используется подзапрос из второй копии исходной таблицы.

Answer (score -1):

Если в запросе есть groub by, то все поля не указанные в group by должны быть в агрегатных функциях.

Если мы хотим получить все варианты value по одному разу, то можно сделать так

```
SELECT MAX(id), MAX(name),value FROM test GROUP BY value
```

UPD В каждой группе выбираем ряд с минимальным id

```
select f.id, f.name, f.value
from (
   select value, min(id) as minid
   from test group by value   
) as x inner join test as f on f.value = x.value and f.id = x.minid;
```

Comment: Нет никакой гарантии, что MAX(id) и MAX(name) вернут значения из одной и той же записи.

Comment: Так в задаче этого и не требуется, требуется чтобы разные value были.

Comment: Ок... вдруг автора такое устроит. Правда, фиг он это сдаст...

Comment: Мне не костыли нужны, а разобраться:)

Comment: Тогда нужно четко написать что нужно и привести пример. Вашу задачу можно понять также "найти строки у которых value встречается только один раз (не повторяется)"

Comment: **все поля не указанные в group by должны быть в агрегатных функциях.** Вранье, не имеет отношения к MySQL, все поля не участвующие в Group By(участвующие кстати тоже) - будут возвращаться из случайной записи(если не установлена сортировка).

Comment: *Вранье, не имеет отношения к MySQL* Не говорите ерунды. лучше почитайте документацию, статья [Server SQL Modes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html).

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков т.е. вы считате, что такой запрос работает? select id, value from test group by value

Comment: Не считаю, а знаю наверняка, в MySQL - прокатит, в PGSQL\MSSQL - не прокатит, будет именно то что вы указали.

Comment: @Владимир Клыков - не могли бы разжевать свой ответ - "все поля не указанные в group by" - о каких полях идет речь? "(если не установлена сортировка)." - а сортировка тут причем и как это работает?

Comment: @Akina https://yadi.sk/i/Mdqfhu0xt9T64g https://yadi.sk/i/8QrLCs9tzHZUgg

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Лучше вот так: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=8ee5366c80238e697235397dc3bf9512).

Comment: Все поля(про которые вы сказали, что они обязаны быть в Group by или агрегатных функциях) - при отсутствии сортировки - будут взяты значения из случайных записей. в случае если есть сортировка - вернутся первые по ходу сортировки записи. Пример запроса с Group by и без агрегатных функций - выше комментарием(там же агрегатная функция во втором запросе чтобы показать что записей более одной)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Это результат отступления от стандарта SQL. В угоду "мышкотыкам", не думающим о логике запроса, которым "и так сойдёт".

Comment: @Akina Не понял к чему этот комментарий =) Я привел вам пример из реальной практики, где MySQL не требует агрегации при группировке =) вполне возможно что в 8 версии это изменилось(я не дожил до 8 версии и ушел в PGsql, но в 5х - агрегация не обязательна.

Comment: Полностью согласен с тем что это отступление от документации, я не говорил что это документировано, а лиш сообщил что для MySQL это не принципиально в отличии от остальных(известных мне) синтаксисов.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Я дал fiddle, где явно указана версия MySQL. И она ни разу не восьмая. Ваша фраза "в 5х - агрегация не обязательна" - не соответствует действительности. Это - документировано. И это - принципиально для тех, кто различает "сделать как надо" и "сделать хоть как-нибудь", для тех, кому важна детерминированность результата.

Comment: @Akina https://yadi.sk/i/LQad8eKoRbzNog вроде версия указана, и указано что это "дефолтные" настройки, об "детерминированности" я тоже кстати написал, если обратите внимание =) Предлогаю прекратить дискуссию, потому что консенсуса по этому вопросу мы скорее всего не достигнем, т.к. вы говорите как делать правильно(и с этим я ничуть не спорю), а я говорю как делать возможно(и не утверждаю что это правильно).

Answer (score -1):

По поводу оператора GROUP BY:

[sql-tutorial.ru](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_group_by_clause.html)

> Предложение GROUP BY используется для определения групп выходных
>   строк, к которым могут применяться агрегатные функции (COUNT, MIN,
>   MAX, AVG и SUM).
>   Если при наличии предложения GROUP BY, в предложении SELECT
>   отсутствуют агрегатные функции, то запрос просто вернет по одной
>   строке из каждой группы. Эту возможность, наряду с ключевым словом
>   DISTINCT, можно использовать для исключения дубликатов строк в
>   результирующем наборе.

Поведение оператора IN с подзапросом, использующим GROUP BY, объяснить не могу, скорее всего возвращаются все id, но предполагаю, что вопрос можно решить с помощью встроенных представлений:

```
SELECT *
FROM test, (SELECT id FROM test GROUP BY value) AS ids
WHERE ids.id = test.id;
```